# implicit declaration error even after including required header

Tags: c, function, declaration, implicit

I get the following error when I run my code:
error: implicit declaration of function ‘mkdtemp’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

This occurs even after including the correct header files for mkdtemp():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: It should be fine. Make sure that you put this `#include` in a correct place for a given compilation unit. And what OS, compiler and libc do you use?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: just fixed the error by trying #define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<stdlib.h>` header is mandated by the C standard.  The C standard makes no reference to a `mkdtemp()` function.  If you're using `gcc -std=c11` or some similar option, only the definitions provided by the C standard are exposed.  If you compile using `gcc -std=gnu11`, then you'll get an indeterminate set of extension features enabled (and `mkdtemp()` would be one of them).

Since [`mkdtemp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) is a POSIX function, you can explicitly request it by defining the appropriate enabling macro before including any standard header.  A command-line option `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` would (probably) do the job, for example; there's also the option of using `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809` but remembering the correct number is harder (it is the date of the POSIX 2008 standard as year and month).

Or you can place the appropriate `#define` at the top of the file:

```
#ifndef _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#endif
```

or:

```
#ifndef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#endif
```

These stanzas allow you to override the POSIX version on the command line.  Simply writing the `#define` without the conditional around it would generate a warning (or error) for a non-benign redefinition of the macro.

There used to be major differences between the POSIX and X/Open functionality — X/Open included some things that POSIX doesn't.  This distinction is smaller these days, and generally, you'll not get into trouble using the X/Open macro.

There are other enabling macros for other platforms, but one of these two will enable the declaration of `mkdtemp()`.  On Linux (RHEL 7.x), `/usr/include/features.h`) documents these enabling macros:

```
/* These are defined by the user (or the compiler)
   to specify the desired environment:

   __STRICT_ANSI__      ISO Standard C.
   _ISOC99_SOURCE       Extensions to ISO C89 from ISO C99.
   _ISOC11_SOURCE       Extensions to ISO C99 from ISO C11.
   _POSIX_SOURCE        IEEE Std 1003.1.
   _POSIX_C_SOURCE      If ==1, like _POSIX_SOURCE; if >=2 add IEEE Std 1003.2;
                        if >=199309L, add IEEE Std 1003.1b-1993;
                        if >=199506L, add IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995;
                        if >=200112L, all of IEEE 1003.1-2004
                        if >=200809L, all of IEEE 1003.1-2008
   _XOPEN_SOURCE        Includes POSIX and XPG things.  Set to 500 if
                        Single Unix conformance is wanted, to 600 for the
                        sixth revision, to 700 for the seventh revision.
   _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED XPG things and X/Open Unix extensions.
   _LARGEFILE_SOURCE    Some more functions for correct standard I/O.
   _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  Additional functionality from LFS for large files.
   _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=N  Select default filesystem interface.
   _BSD_SOURCE          ISO C, POSIX, and 4.3BSD things.
   _SVID_SOURCE         ISO C, POSIX, and SVID things.
   _ATFILE_SOURCE       Additional *at interfaces.
   _GNU_SOURCE          All of the above, plus GNU extensions.
   _REENTRANT           Select additionally reentrant object.
   _THREAD_SAFE         Same as _REENTRANT, often used by other systems.
   _FORTIFY_SOURCE      If set to numeric value > 0 additional security
                        measures are defined, according to level.
```

Note, too, that the manual page for `mkdtemp()` shows what is needed:

```
NAME
       mkdtemp - create a unique temporary directory

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>

       char *mkdtemp(char *template);

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       mkdtemp():
           _BSD_SOURCE
           || /* Since glibc 2.10: */
               (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700)
```

What I called 'enabling macros' are also known as 'Feature Test' macros.

See also POSIX [System Interfaces: General Information: The Compilation Environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02).